# Can't get third monitor to work

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi, displayport

I am running Windows 8.1 (64x bit) with all the latest updates. I have three monitors connected to my PC at work. The connections used are HDMI, DVI and DisplayPort.

The DisplayPort connection is not working for some reason, here is what I get in Display Settings:

[image: display settings]

No matter what I select in the `Multiple displays` drop-down, I get the following:

[image: error]

The graphics on my machine (through CPU-Z) are **AMD Radeon HD 7700 Series**.

What am I doing wrong? What do I need to change in order to get all three monitors working?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We got this problem on a Nvidia card. To use the third monitor the display port adapter had to be an active one.

I know that some AMD card need a dongle to active the third monitor. And some model doesn't support 3 monitor.

Maybe take a look at this thread:
http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/325771-using-3-monitors-on-1-pc

Answer (score 0):

I recently bought a third monitor as well. Everything worked a few weeks until I updated the Nvidia driver to the latest version for my Asus GTX 970. After this I could not get the DP connected monitor to work with the exact error message that you are describing. Going back to the old Nvidia driver did not help either.

The solution was to install the "driver" for the monitor found at the manufacturers site. The driver can be installed through the device manager.

After this, error was gone and my third monitor works again as before!